# add target="_blank" to a link using WP_Admin_Bar::add_node() in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, href, admin, target

I coded this custom widget for the admin-bar of a Wordpress install i'm working on:

```
function custom_admin_bar_link_1($wp_admin_bar) {
$args = array(
    'id' => 'cal-cloudflare',
    'title' => 'Cloudflare', 
    'href' => 'https://dash.cloudflare.com/example.com/caching/configuration',
    'meta' => array(
        'class' => 'cal-cloudflare', 
        'title' => 'Clear Cloudflare Cache'
        )
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_admin_bar_link_1', 999);
```

It works fine, but i want the link to open in a new windows when clicked. I tried this, but to no avail:

```
function custom_admin_bar_link_1($wp_admin_bar) {

$args = array(
    'id' => 'cal-cloudflare',
    'title' => 'Cloudflare', 
    'meta' => array(
        'class' => 'cal-cloudflare', 
        'title' => 'Clear Cloudflare Cache'
        ),
    'a' => array(
        'href' => 'https://dash.cloudflare.com/example.com/caching/configuration', 
        'target' => '_blank'
        )
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_admin_bar_link_1', 999);
```

What needs to be done here?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/add_node/ clearly suggests that `target` needs to be passed as part of the `meta` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```php
function custom_admin_bar_link_1($wp_admin_bar) {
    $args = array(
        'id'    => 'cal-cloudflare',
        'title' => 'Cloudflare', 
        'href'  => 'https://dash.cloudflare.com/example.com/caching/configuration', 
        'meta'  => array(
            'class'  => 'cal-cloudflare', 
            'title'  => 'Clear Cloudflare Cache',
            'target' => '_blank',
        ),
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'custom_admin_bar_link_1', 999);
```

Tested and works.

See:  [`WP_Admin_Bar::add_node()` method parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/add_node/#parameters)